# Monitor unix process with Nagios Core

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, monitoring, nagios, nrpe

I'm begginer with Nagios and i'm trying to monitor if a specific process on my unix machine is up or not.
Server and client are on the same machine : Trying to monitor that machine from a Nagios runing on it.
I've installed Nagios Core 4, nrpe and it's plugins. After looking on the web, I found an answer of how to monitor process using check_procs plugin (up or down) and that's what I actually have in my files :

1- in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg

```
server_address=127.0.0.1
command[check_service]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1: -C $ARG1$
```

2- I created a file called "ubunutu_host.cfg" in /usr/local/nagios/etc/servers/ :

```
# Ubuntu Host configuration file
    define host {
            use                          linux-server
            host_name                    ubuntu_host
            alias                        Ubuntu Host
            address                      127.0.0.1
            register                     1
    }


    define service {
          host_name                       ubuntu_host
          service_description             check_apache2
          check_command                   check_service!apache2
          max_check_attempts              2
          check_interval                  2
          retry_interval                  2
          check_period                    24x7
          check_freshness                 1
          contact_groups                  admins
          notification_interval           2
          notification_period             24x7
          notifications_enabled           1
          register                        1
    }
```

3- In /etc/nagios-plugins/configp/rocs.cfg :

```
define command{
command_name check_service
command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1: -C ‘$ARG1$’
}
```

My probelm is :
when runing this command :

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1: -C apache2
```

that's what I'm having as a result

```
PROCS OK: 7 processes with command name 'apache2' | procs=7;;1:;0;
```

BUT In Nagios, below what I'm having (apache2 is always critical) :
[Problem proc apache2 is always shown critical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Snh9.png)

Comment: Help guys! Thanks

Comment: https://serverfault.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while ServerFault covers admin questions and AskUbuntu covers general questions.

Comment: Try run this command `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1: -C apache2` as Nagios user and also try replace `‘$ARG1$’` to `"$ARG1$"`, just for the case...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, NRPE is used to make and receive **remote** plugin calls. You don't specify which server you are modifying `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` on, but your check command is `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs` which means that Nagios is running this plugin **locally**, and perhaps that is what you want, I don't know, but in that case there is no point in involving NRPE at all.

Since you mention that you get the output you want when "running" the command (you don't specify as what user):

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1: -C apache2
```

I'm guessing that the user that you are running this as actually can see your `apache2` processes, while the user running the actual Nagios check cannot. Try using `su` to change into your Nagios user and see if there's a difference in output.